# Объявление переменной async методом vue3 composition api

Tags: async-await, vue3

Есть метод, который возвращает `Promise` со значением `123`.

```js
const func = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(123);
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

Я хочу с помощью него объявить переменную, чтобы после отработки метода она стала равна `123`

Что-то подобное:

```js
const a = ref((async ()=>await func())());
```

^ эта тема становится равна `Promise`, не смотря на то, что `async` `await` присутствует

Понятно, что это спокойно делается через `onMounted`. Задача именно все сделать внутри `ref()`.